# read XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml, utf-8

I'm trying to write a plugin to read data from XML file

inside test.xml there is:

```
<data>
    <items>
        <item test1="Arabic Words"></item>
        <item test2="English Words"></item>
    </items>
</data>
```

and the code is :

```
# coding: utf-8

from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')

test1 = itemlist[0].attributes['test1'].value
test2 = itemlist[1].attributes['test2'].value

print(test1)
print(test2)
```

But I encounter a problem with coding: I can't set it to utf-8.

How can I make `minidom` interpret files with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Have you tried parsing with `xml.sax`?

Comment: `@mr.somebody`  I guess the answer was no then......also, what is your problem that you are getting for not setting it to UTF-8. Could you post the error message or at least show your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, valid XML begins with a XML pseudotag, containing the encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
```

`minidom` should respect that; if your file has such a tag but isn't interpreted as UTF-8, you should file a bug against `minidom`; but I'd generally expect that your files simply don't contain this line.

You can use

```
minidom.parseString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + open("file.xml","r").read())
```

to work around that (but I recommend fixing your XML files).

Comment: did you fix your files or add the string clutch? By the way (not much of criticism, more meant as an inspiration): When publicly writing something, or addressing someone in an email, try to avoid using "u"; stay with "you", you sound a lot less like teenagers sending short messages.

Comment: yep I add this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: then xmldoc = minidom.parseString("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + open("test.xml","r").read())

Comment: you *either* add the string to the files, *or* use my `parseString`. Please try to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

Either use encode/decode functions or the import codecs.

Example: 
    x = 'abcd'
    y = x.encode('utf-8')
    y.decode('utf-8')

Just use encoding/decoding and use minidom to parse a string instead of passing a file name.

Comment: I just tried it with the same file you're using; it worked both with encode/decode, without encode/decode, with BOM, without BOM... the problem must be someplace else, minidom parses the file without a hitch.